# Digital Ocean LAMP stack z-panel installation "cannot execute binary file" on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lamp

Having an issue installing z-panel on a Digital Ocean VPS running Unbuntu 12.04. Specifically, when I try to execute the installer I get the following error:

> installer-10-1-0-ubuntu-64.sh.x: cannot execute binary file.

Can anyone shed any light on this error? I've re-attempted the install about five times with no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out …

The LAMP stack image from Digital Ocean is 32-bit, not 64-bit. Downloaded the 32-bit installer and it worked just fine.